# Read INI to class const PHP

Tags: php, class, constants

I'm receiving the error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';'` on the TEXT line when trying to run the following code. I really need to be able to write the contents to `Config::TEXT`. Any idea as to where I'm going wrong?

```
class Config {
    const DB_HOST     = 'localhost:3388',
          DB_NAME     = 'otplatform',
          DB_USER     = 'root',
          DB_PASS     = '',
          DEBUG       = true,
          LANGUAGE    = "en",
          TEXT        = parse_ini_file('translate/' . LANGUAGE . '.ini',1);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't declare multiple constants like that. Use this to define multiples:

```
$constants = array(
    'ONE'   => 1,
    'TWO'   => 2,
    'THREE' => 3,
);

apc_define_constants('numbers', $constants);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.apc-define-constants.php

Use either of the following conventions:

```
define("CONSTANT", "Hello world.");
```

Within a class scope:

```
const test = 'foobar!';
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php

Also to answer your question you can't parse a file during definition.